# Can a decimal database field or a decimal form field accept an integer like 100 instead of 100.00?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, numbers, sqldatatypes

Will the decimal database field store the integer 100 as 100.00

Comment: It depends how the **column** is defined.  If it is defined as `decimal(XXX, 2)`, where XXX is 5 or greater, then yes.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't specified which SQl database you're using. These comments hold for MySQl 8

MySQl will accept any valid numeric data and coerce them to the format specified for a DECIMAL column, rounding as necessary. For example

```
 100     => 100.00
 100.123 => 100.12   -- rounded down
 100.129 => 100.13   -- rounded up
```

Note that the precision maintained by MySQL may not be available in the language you are using to communicate with it. PHP will not store a specific number of decimal places, and the quirks of floating point mathematics may mean that decimal fraction is represented with many more decimals than you expect. It may also treat DECIMAl numbers with no fractional part as an integer for output purposes.

To be sure that your output matches your requirements it might be necessary to use a formatting function like `printf()`

For example (in PHP)

```
printf("%.2f",100); // 100.00
```

Or in Javascript

```
num = 100;
num = num.toFixed(2)   // "100.00"
```

Answer (score -2):

For db field, it is impossible to accept an integer like 100 instead of 100.00.